# Como redimensionar uma imagem usando UWP?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp

Tenho esse código:

```
var file = await ImageChooser.GetSelectedImageAsStorageFile();

var sasUri = await Vm.GetBlobSasUri(file.Name);

var blob = await file.UploadToBlob(sasUri);

await Vm.ImageSelected(blob.Uri);
```

Preciso redimensionar a imagem antes de subir para o blob.

[Tentei isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019595/how-to-copy-and-resize-image-in-windows-10-uwp?answertab=votes#tab-top):

Mas o problema é que a função retorna uma bitmap, e no meu caso não é necessário uma cópia.

Lembrando que com UWP (aplicativos para windows 10), não é possível usar o System.Drawing.Image.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar essa função.

```
public async Task ResizeImage(byte[] imageData, int reqWidth, int reqHeight, int quality)
{
    var memStream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
    IRandomAccessStream imageStream = memStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
    var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
    if (decoder.PixelHeight > reqHeight || decoder.PixelWidth > reqWidth)
    {
        using (imageStream)
        {
            var resizedStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(resizedStream, decoder);
            double widthRatio = (double) reqWidth/decoder.PixelWidth;
            double heightRatio = (double) reqHeight/decoder.PixelHeight;
            double scaleRatio = Math.Min(widthRatio, heightRatio);
            if (reqWidth == 0)
                scaleRatio = heightRatio;
            if (reqHeight == 0)
                scaleRatio = widthRatio;
            uint aspectHeight = (uint) Math.Floor(decoder.PixelHeight*scaleRatio);
            uint aspectWidth = (uint) Math.Floor(decoder.PixelWidth*scaleRatio);
            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = aspectHeight;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = aspectWidth;
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            resizedStream.Seek(0);
            var outBuffer = new byte[resizedStream.Size];
            await resizedStream.ReadAsync(outBuffer.AsBuffer(), (uint)resizedStream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);
            return outBuffer;
        }
    }
    return imageData;
}
```

Ela usará o buffer dos pixels da imagem para gerar outro buffer, que poderá ser usado para criar uma nova imagem.